# Make a Cylinder "Coney"

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder, and I wish to make it more "coney" so to speak.

[image]

How do I go about?

Comment: Create a cylinder, select its bottom, scale it down?

Comment: I assumed that I could do that, but when I try to select the bottom, I only ever manage to select either the full cylinder, or nothing at all. Am I doing something thoroughly idiotic here or...?

Comment: You're making the selection in object mode! You first need to select the cylinder then hit tab to enter edit mode! Then you can cycle through vertex select, edge select or face select by hitting 1,2 or 3 respectively (you'd want to use 3 in this scenario) then simply select the face and scale :)

Comment: AAAAAH! There we go! :D Thank you, good people, for your help and your patience with this hopeless newbie! :D

Comment: Other possibility: when you want a cone, add a _Cone_ instead of a _Cylinder_ and in the tools menu on the bottom left of the viewport adjust _Radius 1_ (bottom radius) and _Radius 2_ (top radius) to your liking. @moonboots Why create a cylinder at all? ;)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Oh yes you're right, I didn't know that the top radius could be something else than 0. That said the question was "I have a cylinder"   ;)

Comment: ... or, if you have a cylinder with multiple divisions down the side, give it a _Simple Deform_ > 'Taper'  modifier